# Python Regex to match any combinatuon of what is isalnum() and isspace() but not two simultanious newline symbols

Tags: python, regex

I want to split

```
"Use a regexp that matches any combination\nthat satisfies Python's\n\nisalphanumeric() or isspace() functions, but   not two simultanionus\nnewline symbols"
```

into a

```
["A regexp that matches any combination\nthat satisfies Python", "s ", "isalphanumeric", "or isspace", " functions","  but   not two simultanionus\nnewline symbols"]
```

list using findall() method.

I have written:

```
re.findall("[\w\s]*", text)
```

but now I need to add some thing like "except for \n\n" which currenly sattisfies my expression.

Comment: this `re.findall("[\w ]+", text)` would be fine.

Comment: then how it matches a single newline character? You need to explain more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([\w\s]+?)(?=\n{2}|['(),]|$)
```

Try this.See demo.Use match rather than split.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/11

```
re.findall("([\w\s]+?)(?=\n{2}|['(),]|$)", text)
```